# SSO for Intranet SharePoint Online Site on windows startup

Tags: sharepoint-online, single-sign-on, windows

I'd like to ask you if it's possible to have a mandatory Single Sign-On when the employees log in to their laptops/desktops. We want to automatically open the intranet communication SharePoint Online Site, upon windows startup.

If yes, what is the best way to do it?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shortcut for SharePoint online site, then right click on the start menu and choose run,type `shell:common startup` to access the **common startup folder for all users**, click ok.

[image]

Then drag the site shortcut to this folder to ensure that the intranet communication SharePoint Online site is automatically opened when Windows starts.